# Micrsoft Graph API To-Do Lists

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get a list of all my taska in the Microsoft to-do app over the Microsoft graph API v1.0 using python.

I was able to establish a connection to the graph API and query some user data, meaning that authentication should not be the issue.

However, I get a 404 error:

```
MainError(additional_data={}, code='itemNotFound', details=None, inner_error=InnerError(additional_data={'code': 'MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI', 'date': DateTime(2024, 1, 10, 6, 25, 7, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC'))}, client_request_id='246435eb-2520-48f7-a4a5-691f8b050132', date=None, odata_type=None, request_id='f43b76c7-dd96-4418-bd1a-4587334f148d'), message='Item not found', target=None)
```

I tried to get the lists with the following code:

```
await self.app_client.users.by_user_id(user-id).todo.lists.get()
```

Where user-id is my user ID. The user ID should be correct, since I was able to retrieve user information with this user ID.

Comment: Please review the answer below and see if it helps. Happy to dig deeper should you still be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Try and run this request(https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/todo/lists ) on [Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and see if you are getting results. You can try different user ids.
The error message usually occurs when the mailbox is not located in M365. Ensure that the mailbox is on Exchange Online. Here is a link to helpful documentation- [REST API is not yet supported error - Exchange | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/exchange/troubleshoot/user-and-shared-mailboxes/rest-api-is-not-yet-supported-for-this-mailbox-error)